# Access token not working Azure AD custom policy

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I made a custom policy for Azure B2C, added jwt.ms as a reply URL and everything seems to be working fine. When I log in, I get redirected to jwt.ms showing the token and it's contents. However when I try to link my angular frontend to this custom policy, it does not seem to work. In need the response type `id_token token`, but when I use this response type I get the error "*This application does not have sufficient permissions against this web resource to perform the operation.*"

When I use the response type `id_token` it seems to work fine and I get a reply with the JWT token.

I thought the problem might be in the *Implicit grant* settings under applications, so I have tried enabling *Access tokens* and *ID tokens* for all applications but this did not help.

[Implicit grant settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWl1y.png)

The request looks as follows:

```
https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?p=b2c_1a_signup_signin&client_id={client_id}
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2F&response_type=id_token%20token
&scope=openid%20https%3A%2F%2F{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com%2Fapi%2Fuser_impersonation
&nonce={nonce}
&state={state}
```

So if you replace the characters it looks like this:

```
https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?p=b2c_1a_signup_signin&client_id={client_id}
&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/&response_type=id_token token
&scope=openid https://{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/api/user_impersonation
&nonce={nonce}
&state={state}
```

I expect the login flow to return both the JWT ID token and an access token.

Edit: 
I created a whole new B2C tenant with a standard Signupsignin user flow and I still experience the same issues. So I concluded that it is not a custom policy issue, but an issue caused by a configuration in Azure or the front-end application.

Comment: Have you enable implicit grant on Azure portal?

Comment: Where do I do that, isn't that the option I enabled on all applications like described?

Comment: Please take a look. And let me know if you have any more concern. Thanks

Comment: Hi Tim. In the Azure AD B2C blade, have you assigned access by the front-end app to the back-end API, through the **API Access** option?

Comment: What do you mean with back-end API and front-end app?

Comment: @TimH I have updated my answer please take a look and let me know if you have any more problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of experiment I come to know about your problem.  I guess you are not trying in a right format. Even I don't know which document you are refereed to. Okay the first problem is...

You are getting this error `"This application does not have sufficient permissions against this web resource to perform the operation"`

**Reason**

You have not set `API access` in your target application on azure portal. To achieve that you have add `API access` on your application.

Let say you have two `Published scopes` on your B2C tenant application like below:

[image]

**Create API Access**

To avoid above error `Add` API access. To do that , go to your application select `API access` after that you will see a `Add` button on top. click and right side `API access` window will be open just click `Ok`. See the below screen shot:

[image]

After successful `API Access` It should looks like below

[image]

> **Note:** Hope It will solve your error while you are trying to send request.

**B2C id_token and Access Token**

Follow the below steps for `Id_token`

**ID Token Access Process**

> https://YourB2CTenant.b2clogin.com/tfp/YourB2CTenant.onmicrosoft.com/YourPolicy/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
>
> client_id= YourApplicationId
>
> &redirect_uri= Your reply from Application
>
> &scope=openid
>
> &response_type=id_token

**Take a look below at `Id_token`:**

[image]

> **Note:** Just fill out the above format and paste at your browser with no space between. If is it correct then a sign in page will be
>   prompted. After sign in you will be given id_token on your browser.

**B2C Access Token**

Follow the below format In `POSTMAN`:

> Grant Type:authorization_code
>
> Callback URL: Your Reply URL
>
> AuthURL:https://YourTenant.b2clogin.com/YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com/YourFlow/PolicyName/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
>
> Access Token URL:
>   https://YourTenant.b2clogin.com/YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=YourFlow/PolicyName
>
> Client ID: Your Application Id
>
> Client Secret = Application Key
>
> Scope= any of your `Published scopes`

**Post Man request Process**

Go to postman and click on `Authorization` Tab and Select `type` as `OAuth 2.0` See the below screen shot:

[image]

For getting access token click on `Get New Access Token` You will be prompt following window fill out it with above mentioned format.

[image]

[image]

After hitting `Request Token` button you will be prompted a sign in window after successful login you will get `access_token` in response. Like below:

[image]

> **Note:** In B2C there is no supported way to get `Id-Token and access_token together in a single request. You have to achieve it in
>   separate request. For more details you could refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-access-tokens#request-a-token)

If you still have any problem please feel free to share here in  comment. Thank you and happy coding!

Comment: I've been trying to fix this for about 8 hours; this finally solved my issue with getting the access token, thanks!

Comment: Good to hear that it helped.